# Fitted Function in R

Tags: r

If I define myCDF here:

```
myCDF<- mvdc(gumbelCopula(3,dim=2), margins=c("norm","exp"), 
     paramMargins=list(list(mean=10,sd=2),list(rate=2)))
```

Then I generate x

```
x <- rmvdc(myCDF,1000)
```

Then here goes my problem: if I use the fitted function here, can somebody explain why i should put myCDF which I already define and the `c(3,9,1,1)` that is the one

```
Fitted<-fitMvdc(x, myCDF, c(3,9,1,1))
```

Comment: General request: please give package reference when working with functions not in the standard base distro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a slightly modified version of the example on the help page for `fitMvbdc` in package:copula. Attempts to fit parameters to an unknown copula of unknown parameters need some sort of constraint (like the dimensions and type of marginals, because there are an infinite set of functional forms that could be chosen. With copula fitting the task is to construct the "interior"  or the covariance of the MV distribution. It's really no different in principle than fitting distribution to univariate data, where need to specify the functional form before estimating parameters.

Or ... if you are mainly concerned about the need for starting values, ... You should read up more on optimization procedures and how they can go wrong when starting the process far from the "true" values.